# How do I use my voice, no text, to extract a line from a text file?

Tags: python, text-files, voice

The below code is a code where you type a key phrase from a text file, and the output is the line that corresponds with that key phrase.  For example, I have a text file (bibletext.txt) that has all of the bible verses from Genesis to Exodus.  The code works below, for example, if I type Psalms 12:1, the key phrase, then the line will be the output, which is the bible verse Psalms 12:1, and the computer will speak it to me.

What I want is instead of typing Psalms 12:1, I want to SPEEK Psalms 12:1 into my microphone, and have the output be produced.  How do I keep the similar extraction code below, but use my voice to say Psalms 12:1, or any key phrase, instead of typing it?  Thanks!

```
import pyttsx3
import re

engine = pyttsx3.init()
with open('bibletext.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'Psalms 12:1', line):
            print (line)
            break
engine.say(line)
engine.runAndWait()
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: 1. Transform your voice into text using some library. 2. Use the text like you normally would. You should look up 'speech recognition python' and see what libraries you can use. Then, if you have problems implementing a *specific* library for your speech recognition, you can ask about it here.

Comment: Do you have any specific code that can make it happen, thanks